# XOPEncodingStreamWriter incompatible with DataHandlerWriter -- WAS8.5.5.2 + AXIOM

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, websphere-8, axiom

Can any one tell me why the below error comes...

Unable to perform rendering due to exception (**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.util.stax.xop.XOPEncodingStreamWriter incompatible with org.apache.axiom.ext.stax.datahandler.DataHandlerWriter**)

I am using axiom in my application which got deployed in WAS 8.5.5.2. The same application is working fine in Jboss6 with axiom-impl,axiom-api,axiom-ext 1.2.12 jars but getting the below error in Websphere. No clues at all.

**StackTrace:**

```
 stacktrace=org.apache.axiom.util.stax.XMLStreamWriterUtils.internalGetDataHandlerWriter(XMLStreamWriterUtils.java:71)

org.apache.axiom.util.stax.XMLStreamWriterUtils.writeDataHandler(XMLStreamWriterUtils.java:134)
 org.apache.axiom.util.stax.XMLStreamWriterUtils.writeDataHandler(XMLStreamWriterUtils.java:134)
com.myapplication.mdivrs.axis2.mdivrsStub$RenderDocument.serialize(mdivrsStub.java:1503) 
com.myapplication.mdivrs.axis2.mdivrsStub$RenderDocumentE.serialize(mdivrsStub.java:2607)    
com.myapplication.mdivrs.axis2.mdivrsStub$RenderDocumentE.serialize(mdivrsStub.j ava:2593)
org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource.serialize(ADBDataSource.java:90)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:781)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:967)       
org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)        
org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:207)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)             
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
```

Comment: Did you try to change classloader on your web module to ParentLast?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587270/classcast-exception-during-rendering-while-using-axiom-in-was-8-5-5-2)?

Comment: hi, yes tried but found many issues other than this issue. I am not able to identify like was the error from websphere or AXIOM. So asked couples of times unfortunately ..

Comment: Hi, I found org.apache.axiom.util.stax.xop.XOPEncodingStreamWriter class is not at all using but still why this class have became part of my execution. Any clues to exclude this class